# Regex not allowing backslash

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem with my regex for not allowing backslash after the allowed characters. I have tested this through regex testers online and it is working, however when I use it on my c#, it returns true at all cost.

This is my regex : `var myRegex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((([._-][^\/<>()[\\]_.,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"\\\/))$");`

[My Regex](http://rubular.com/r/Enm1MshRDP)

Input samples:

```
hello-\world : Negative   
hello\world : Negative  
hello/world : Negative  
hello : Positive
```

However, this is the result when I implement it in c#

Input samples:

hello-\world : Positive (Which should be negative)
hello\world : Negative
hello/world : Negative
hello : Positive

I can't seem to find what's wrong with negating the backslash. Kinda hard to debug and check why the c# version of the Regex gives a different result.

Thanks for all the feedback.

**EDIT:** Updated the regex to c#

Comment: Did you try double backslashes?

Comment: @TahaPaksu Yes, I did try that, still passing through it.

Comment: could you please put some shed of light on your business logic ? Then it can be understood better

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman I am trying to negate the \ or backslashes. The backslashes however when combined with succeeding allowed characters are being allowed, which shouldn't be.

Comment: You could try adding a $ at the end of the regex. That way the regex has to match the full string, not just a substring, which is what is usually tested for. Though, without knowing exactly what code you have, that is calling around the regex object, it quite difficult to why you are getting false positives.

Comment: @RasmusHansen I have updated the code, I have the $ at the end, sorry for not completing the regex itself in c#

Comment: Couldn't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain the regex or what you are trying to achieve? There should be an alphanumeric string at the beginning, then the allowable characters 0 or more of them.

Comment: @TahaPaksu I am trying to negate the \ or backslashes. The backslashes however when combined with succeeding allowed characters are being allowed, which shouldn't be. Please do check my input samples for you to visualize what I am trying to do.

Comment: See this part of your pattern: `[^\/<>()[\\]_.,;:\\s@\"]+`. It "allows" ``\``. Just add ``\\\\`` there (actually, you should use `@""` to declare the pattern and then you can replace ``\\`` with ``\`` in the pattern to shorten it). See https://regex101.com/r/Lmx8b2/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in your regex. Wrote some test to correct it:

```
        var myRegex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((([._-][^\\/<>()[\\]_.,;:\\s@\"\\\\]+)*)|(\".+\"\\\\/))$");
        Assert.IsFalse(myRegex.IsMatch("hello-\\world"));
        Assert.IsFalse(myRegex.IsMatch("hello\\world"));
        Assert.IsFalse(myRegex.IsMatch("hello/world"));
        Assert.IsTrue(myRegex.IsMatch("hello"));
```

Your first group allows dash, then didn't disallow backslashes.

Comment: I'd further inprove the readablility by using @(in c#) and character classes:@"^\d+((([._-][^\/<>()[\]_.,;:\s@"\\]+)*)|(".+"\\/))$"

Comment: @Chriz Sorry for this, kinda newbie to Regex itself, but adding @ results to unexpected characters in this part `\]+)*)|(`